# I am not able to remove text file data

Tags: java

Here is my file data

```
A -1 D -1 G -1 I -1 K -1 -2
A -1 D -1 G -1 J -1 K -1 -2
B -1 D -1 G -1 I -1 L -1 -2
C -1 E B -1 G -1 I -1 L -1 -2
C -1 F -1 H -1 I B -1 L -1 -2
```

Code:

```
File file = new File("input.txt");/*input file where above data is stored.*/
fw = new FileWriter(file);/* file writer is used*/
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
FileReader fr = new FileReader("input.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

while( (verify=br.readLine()) != null )
{ 
  if(verify != null)
  { 
          if(verify.contains("A"))
          {
           putData = verify.replaceAll("A", "");/*replacing character 'A' with null*/
           bw.write(putData); 
          }

          if(verify.contains("B"))/* for character 'B'*/
          {
         putData = verify.replaceAll("B", "");
         bw.write(putData);
          }
   }
}
```

I want to remove the characters 'A' ,'B' etc. from the file without disturbing rest of content.

I am trying to update the file with above code, but not able to update it.Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: .replaceAll("[A-Z]", "");

Comment: You can't do simultaneous read write transaction on same file(u can but not preferred)...why not create a new file and write into it?

Comment: It seems you are trying to read and write the same file, `input.txt`. Unfortunately, that is not supposed to work. Write a new file first, then replace the old file with the new one afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't read a file and change the file's content all in one pass.

- First, read the file and save each line you want to keep in a
  temporary list.  Then clear the content of the file.
- Then loop through your temporary list and write each line back to the
  file.
- Finally, flush() the buffer and close the File.

  You can `filter / edit` any line you want either before saving to the list or before writing back to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You just do like this:

```
{  file_put_contents
     ($filename, str_replace
        ($line . "<whatever character u want to delete>", "",file_get_contents($filename)));
 }
```

Comment: What language is that? (The question is tagged java.)